# How to use parameters inside parameters.json file in Azure Logic App Workflow definition

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-workflow-automation

I have a requirement to use the parameters inside the workflow parameters Object similar to below. But I am failing with the Azure Validation.

```
"parameters": {
    "$apprelatedparams": {
      "value": {
        "testId": "<GUID>",
        "testGroupName": "<GroupName>"
      }
    },
    "$connections": {
      "value": {
        "connectionName": {
          "connectionId": /test/@parameters['$apprelatedparams']['testId']/resourceGroups/@parameters['$apprelatedparams']['testGroupName']/providers/connectionName,
          "id": /test/@parameters['$apprelatedparams']['testId']/providers/testName
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the complete workflow with parameters object -

```
{
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
      "Response": {
        "inputs": {
          "body": "\"message\": \"Hello World!\"",
          "statusCode": 200
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "Response"
      }
    },
    "contentVersion": "",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {},
  },
  "parameters": {
      "$apprelatedparams": {
      "value": {
        "testId": "TestID",
        "testGroupName": "GroupName"
      }
    },
     "$apprelatedparamstest": {
      "value": {
        "testsId": "@parameters['$apprelatedparams']['testId']",
        "testGroupsName": "@parameters['$apprelatedparams']['testGroupName']"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Functions in expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#functions-in-expressions) are called using parenthesis and not brackets. Therefore, you should transform your file into :

```
"parameters": {
    "$apprelatedparams": {
      "value": {
        "testId": "<GUID>",
        "testGroupName": "<GroupName>"
      }
    },
    "$connections": {
      "value": {
        "connectionName": {
          "connectionId": "/test/@parameters('apprelatedparams')['testId']/resourceGroups/@parameters('apprelatedparams')['testGroupName']/providers/connectionName",
          "id": "/test/@parameters('apprelatedparams')['testId']/providers/testName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

See also [Expressions for Workflow Definition Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#expressions) as it explains what outputs you should expect depending on how you construct the call.

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned, but it is failing validation and through errors like - @parameters('apprelatedparams')['testId'] not found.

Comment: Indeed, as per Swetha answer, some " " are missing ! Edited !

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because of the structure of the json. Here is the json code that worked for me.

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "$apprelatedparams": {
      "value": {
        "testId": "<GUID>",
        "testGroupName": "<GroupName>"
      }
    },
    "$connections": {
      "value": {
        "connectionName": {
          "connectionId": "test/@parameters['$apprelatedparams']['testId']/resourceGroups/@parameters['$apprelatedparams']['testGroupName']/providers/connectionName",
          "id": "/test/@parameters['$apprelatedparams']['testId']/providers/testName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned, but it is failing validation and through errors like - @parameters['$apprelatedparams']['testId'] not found.
I am trying these parameters Object below the workflow definition like 
{
  "definition": {<Actual Workflow Definition>},
  "parameters":{<Above Given Parameters Object>}
}

Comment: can you please provide us with what you are passing through it.

Comment: Please check the updated question. I provided a sample workflow definition

Comment: @Dev-VKP Can you please help us with what are the connectors you are using

Comment: I am using only Office 365 Connection. But going forward, I will integrate more connectors

Comment: Can you please provide somemore information or screenshots of your logic app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239397/discussion-between-dev-vkp-and-swethakandikonda-mt).